Previously pushed object values is updated by newly pushed object values on using array.push()
I am trying to turn 1 object into 2 with different value
{
    "item": "FUZZY NEKO CAT LITTER 10L",
    "size": "10L",      
    "e_qty": 137,
    "e_total": 23992.81,
    "price": 178,
    "wh1": "WH-A-2    ",
    "wh2": "WH-C-135    ",
    "id": 25
}

ideally, i want to have this 2 object instead
{
        "item": "FUZZY NEKO CAT LITTER 10L",
        "size": "10L",            
        "e_total": 23992.81,
        "price": 178,
        "wh": 'WH-A',
        "f_qty": 2,           
        "id": 25
},  {
        "item": "FUZZY NEKO CAT LITTER 10L",
        "size": "10L",      
        "e_total": 23992.81,
        "price": 178,
        "wh": 'WH-C',
        "f_qty": 135,           
        "id": 25
}

but the problem is on my loop, even though i already pushed the first element to an array, its still get overridden by the latest push. heres my code
 var obj_array = []; 

 for (var i = skus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      
        var wh1_arr = [];
        var wh2_arr = [];
        var wh3_arr = [];
    
       if(skus[i].id == 25){
    
    if(skus[i].wh1 !=''){
        
        if(skus[i].wh1 !=''){
          
          wh1_arr = skus[i].wh1.split('-');
          var x = skus[i];
          if(wh1_arr.length == 3){
    
            skus[i].wh = wh1_arr[0]+'-'+wh1_arr[1];
            skus[i].f_qty = wh1_arr[2];
            obj_array.push(skus[i]);
            x = '';
          }else{
             skus[i].wh = x.wh1;
             skus[i].f_qty = x.e_qty;
            obj_array.push(skus[i]);
          }
        }

    if(skus[i].wh2 !=''){
        
          wh2_arr = skus[i].wh2.split('-');
          var y = skus[i];
          if(wh2_arr.length == 3){
             skus[i].wh = wh2_arr[0]+'-'+wh2_arr[1];
             skus[i].f_qty = wh2_arr[2];
            obj_array.push(skus[i]);
          }else{
             skus[i].wh = y.wh2;
             skus[i].f_qty = y.e_qty;
            obj_array.push(skus[i]);
            y ='';
          }
        }
}

the result is
{
        "item": "FUZZY NEKO CAT LITTER 10L",
        "size": "10L",            
        "e_total": 23992.81,
        "price": 178,
        "wh": 'WH-C',
        "f_qty": 2,           
        "id": 135
},  {
        "item": "FUZZY NEKO CAT LITTER 10L",
        "size": "10L",      
        "e_total": 23992.81,
        "price": 178,
        "wh": 'WH-C',
        "f_qty": 135,           
        "id": 25
}

why is the first pushed object is still being over-written by the latest one? I want the first element to have f_qty = 2 and wh = 'wh-a' ..
thanks for clarifying :)

Because you keep on modifying the same object (skus[i]) and end up pushing that same object in the array twice...

hi @RobbyCornelissen thx for the comment.. shouldnt be the previously pushed skus[i] not be affected by latest modification since it was already saved to an array? that was I was thinking ..

I tried it on php. same concept and I get the desired result .. hmm.. js is complicated xD
